# InjectPresenter doesn't work in Activity with library Moxy

Tags: android, mvp, moxy

I'm creating MVP android application with library Moxy, but when i'm trying call method from presenter in activity i have error  `lateinit property mainPresenter has not been initialized`

My View interface code

```
@StateStrategyType(AddToEndSingleStrategy::class)
interface MainView : MvpView {

fun startLoading()
fun endLoading()
fun showError(message: String)
fun getResult(textFromPresenter: String)
```

}

Presenter:

```
@InjectViewState
class MainPresenter : MvpPresenter<MainView>() {

fun getText() {
    viewState.startLoading()
    viewState.endLoading()
    viewState.getResult("Text from Presenter")

}
```

}

and Activity:

```
lass MainActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity(), MainView {

@InjectPresenter
lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    button.setOnClickListener { mainPresenter.getText() }

}
//all implementation methods
```

and gradle:

```
implementation 'tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x:1.7.0'
implementation 'tech.schoolhelper:moxy-x-androidx:1.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.5.5'
```

Comment: Same here, wont inject